# From $\det(A^T)=\det(A)$ to equivalence of row/column expansion of determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra

(Say $A \in M_{n\times n}(F)$.) I just finished the proof of $\det(A^T)=\det(A),$ and I have two questions about this

- How can I use this fact to prove that the definition of determinant(first row expansion) is equivalent to column expansion?
- Can I mix both elementary column operation(s) and elementary row operation(s) when simplify matrix?

Appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first point, notice that every operation on the rows of $A$ has an exact equivalent operation on the columns of $A^T$. This can be proved using [shear matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_matrix).

As to your second point, you can indeed mix row and column operations which can prove useful in some situations:

$$D=\begin{bmatrix}
1  &   2     &    3    &    4  \\
0   & 0 &  0 &  1  \\
0  & 5  &    6  & 7   \\
0  &    8    &    9    &     10
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This examples naturally leads you to expand on both rows and columns.

Comment: Could I explain like this: When I doing column operation(s) on $A$, I'm actually doing row operation(s) on $A^T$, but since $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$, so expansion over column works?

Comment: Saying that row operations on $A$ is the same as columns operations on $A^T$ does not depend on the determinant. However, to prove that row expansion is equivalent to column expansion, you may say that since $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$, you can do a column expansion on $A$ because it is the same as row expansion on $A^T$ which has the same determinant.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I got it!